# Trigger anonymous function inside setInterval immediately

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, setinterval

So I have a timer that looks like this

```
my_timer = setInterval(function(){
    do_something_amazing();
    do_more.stuff_here();
    var etc_etc = "foo" + bar;
}, 1000);
```

And I want it to run immediately, and every second after that. I tried appending () to the end of the function, but that caused it to run only once (because it is not returning the function itself to the setInterval?). I then tried to `return this;` so that it would possibly return the function itself, but that did no good either. That was a random guess.

Is there any way I can get this to work without creating a named function? Thanks!

Comment: About appending `()`: indeed, you're setting the returned value as a parameter, not a reference to the function. BTW, why don't you want to create a named function?

Comment: No reason really, I was just hoping to learn some fancy new trick to call an anonymous function immediately, while having it return itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee):

```
my_timer = setInterval((function(){     
    do_something_amazing();     
    do_more.stuff_here();     
    var etc_etc = "foo" + bar;
    return arguments.callee; 
})(), 1000);
```

Comment: Isn't callee deprecated? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee

Comment: If i understand correctly, only when used like "
functionName.arguments.callee".

Comment: From MDC: "callee as a property of Function.arguments is no longer used.", says nothing about it being deprecated when used in a function.

Comment: @Shane: Shurdoof is right; `arguments.callee` is only explicitly forbidden when in ES262-5 [strict mode](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Annex_C.htm).

Comment: +1 cleaner and cleverer than my answer.. i didn't know about `callee`

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't technically create any *named* functions, but I'm not sure why you'd want to do it:

```
(function(func) {
    func();
    setInterval(func, 1000);
})(function() {
    do_something_amazing();
    do_more.stuff_here();
    var etc_etc = "foo" + bar;
});
```

Comment: Though correct, this looks rather not obvious to me what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
function startItUp()
{
   bla();
   setInterval( bla, 1000);
}

function bla()
{
    do_something_amazing();
    do_more.stuff_here();
    var etc_etc = "foo" + bar;
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: It works, but the OP asked: “Is there any way I can get this to work **without creating a named function**?” Moreover, I'd change the order of `bla()` and `setInterval()`: if `bla` takes some time, there will be a difference in timing between the first two invocations and the next ones. See [this nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval/731625#731625) to read how `setInterval` works.